# Amazon DynamoDB for Windows Mobile

Tags: http, amazon-dynamodb, windows-mobile-6.5

I need to use DynamoDB in Win Mobile application (I'm using VS2008 and Smart Device project). I can find a lot of SDK for different platforms at Amazon site, but can't find SDK for Win Mobile. Can I use some tricks to handle this with some of existing SDK?
If no, then it would be great to find some example of using HTTP for that (REST api, or somethig like that). Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The .NET C# SDK is open source and can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net).

I haven't used .NET CF for a long time so I am not aware of the differences between the framework the .NET SDK sln is using and the compact framework you are using.

If it doesn't link automagically, maybe you can take the parts relevant to DynamoDB and fill in the missing pieces with .NET CF ready libraries.

I think starting from the already robust project makes more sense then implementing the REST allover again.